# Unity 5 получить результат работы шейдера

Tags: c#, unity3d, шейдеры

Приведу кусочек шейдера:

```
float4 frag(VertexOutput i) : COLOR {
    // Read inputs
    float4 _a = tex2D( _A, i.uv );
    float4 _b = tex2D( _B, i.uv );
    float4 _t = tex2D( _T, i.uv );

    // Operator
    float4 outputColor = lerp(_a, _b, _t);

    // Return
    return outputColor * _OutputMask;
}
```

Как из скрипта в юнити получить то, что он возвращает: return ...?
Мне просто нужно сохранить результат в переменную и дальше с ним работать.

Answer (score 1):

Недавно экспериментировал с этим. Если коротко, нужно заставить видеокарту отрендерить шейдер в [`RenderTexture`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RenderTexture.html), используя [`Blit()`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Graphics.Blit.html).

1. В редакторе создаем материал с вашим шейдером.
2. В скрипте берем этот материал.
3. В скрипте создаем или берем исходную текстуру, если нужна (в шейдере мы видим `tex2D()`, значит нужна, очевидно).
4. В скрипте создаем экземпляр `RenderTexture` нужного размера и формата.
5. В `Update()` (или когда вам там нужно) вызываем:

   Graphics.Blit(dataTexture, renderTexture, computeMaterial);

, где `dataTexture` — исходная текстура из пункта 3, `renderTexture` — целевая текстура из пункта 4, `computeMaterial` — материал из пунктов 1-2.

Далее нужно из `renderTexture` считать результат с нужных пикселей.

---

Выбор формата для исходной и целевой текстур — несколько каверзный вопрос сам по себе из-за разной поддержки разных форматов разными видеокартами. Я использовал `Alpha8` для исходной, так как мне нужен был всего один канал с наименьшим кол-вом передаваемой информации; и `ARGB32` для целевой.

---

Если нужно получить данные с шейдера **и** при этом его же использовать для выведения картинки на монитор, то, насколько я понимаю, придется два раза им рендерить: один нормальный и один через `Blit()`. Или можно натянуть `RenderTexture` на модель, особенно если это просто плоскость.

---

Если нужны только вычисления, и не нужна поддержка устройств, не умеющих DX11 (а таких еще немало, как я понимаю), то проще и разумнее использовать [вычислительные шейдеры](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ComputeShaders.html).

Comment: Спасибо за информацию. Сейчас как раз вычеслительные шейдеры изучаю. Когда получу более менее приемлемый результат, напишу сюда.